# Asp.net 5 (vnext) custom authentication middleware

Tags: asp.net, authentication, asp.net-identity

I want to learn everything there is to learn about asp.net. And the current thing I'm trying to get the hang of is asp.net middleware.

I want to create a simple middleware that is able to do the authentication by providing some claims.

Unfortunatly I cannot find a whole lot on this topic online. Basically I thought all I needed to do was something like this:

```
 app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {

            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity();
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "Matthias"));
            context.User = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);

            await next.Invoke();

        });
```

Unfortunatly this seems to be crashing the whole application, without any exception-message. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seemed to be a version issue. I was using beta6 and in beta8 this problem does not occur with the same code.